# Recursive programming in decision tree

Tags: python, recursion, decision-tree

I'm programming a decision tree in python. `tree` is an object which has a true branch `tb` and false branch `fb`. Only root nodes have the attribute `results`.

`results` is a dictionary containing count of each target variable (i.e. dependent variable) at the node. I'm working on a binary classification problem, so an example would be a dictionary `{0: 25, 1: 9}`.

I want to create a function `findrootnodes(tree)` which iterates through the tree, down to the root nodes. It should return the list rootnodes. Each element of the list should contain a dictionary. So an example of a decision tree with four root nodes would be `[{0: 25, 1: 9}, {0: 2, 1: 65}, {0: 2, 1: 7}, {0: 52, 1: 4}]`.

How can I do this? My current code is below, but the issue is that it always returns an empty list. If I bring rootnodes out of the function, Python complains that the local variable rootnodes is referenced before it is instantiated.

```
def findrootnodes(tree):   
    rootnodes = []
    if tree.results != None:
        rootnodes += tree.results
    else: 
        findrootnodes(tree.tb)
        findrootnodes(tree.fb)
    return rootnodes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `findrootnodes` function, you never change the value of `rootnodes` for non-result nodes.  That is, when you call `findrootnodes`, you first set:

```
rootnodes = []
```

Assuming that the initial node has no `results`, you then run:

```
    findrootnodes(tree.tb)
    findrootnodes(tree.fb)
```

...neither of which changes the value of `rootnodes`.  And then you return `rootnodes`, which is still an empty list.

I think that what you actually want is:

```
def findrootnodes(tree):   
    rootnodes = []
    if tree.results != None:
        rootnodes.append(tree.results)
    else: 
        rootnodes.extend(findrootnodes(tree.tb))
        rootnodes.extend(findrootnodes(tree.fb))
    return rootnodes
```

Note that I've changed your `+=` here to `.append(...)`, because of this:

```
>>> x = []
>>> x += {'key': 'value'}
>>> x
['key']
```

Trying to add a dictionary to a list via `+=` will treat the dictionary as an iterable, which Python will iterate over *just the keys*.

Comment: Thanks, especially about the part about adding a dictionary to a list via `+=`

Comment: The result becomes like this: [[[{0.0: 10, 1.0: 11}], [{0.0: 157, 1.0: 23}]], [[{0.0: 7, 1.0: 177}], [{0.0: 77, 1.0: 44}]]]

Comment: Is there any way to avoid nested lists?

Comment: Yes, replace the `append` in the `else` with `extend` (see my update to the answer)